# Can I use a design attribute's value in another design attribute datasource?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, design

Let's say I have the following design attribute file for a Lightning Component:

```
<design:component>
<design:attribute
        name="selectedPage"
        label="Selected page"
        description="Use if you want only one specific page to be displayed"
/>
<design:attribute
        name="recordId"
        label="Record"
        datasource="apex://MyItemsPickList"
        description="Select an item"
/>
```

I want to populate the `selectedPage` datasource by fetching values based off of what is selected in my `recordId` field. Is that possible?

Let's say the `recordId` will fetch a list of books. I select one of those books. Now I want my `selectedPage` to use that `recordId` to fetch the book record and populate itself with all the pages of the book (let's I assume I only have about 10 pages so it doesn't sound ridiculous).

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible right now. Each option has to be calculated independent of other selected attributes.